# AngularJS - Object assignment does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good afternoon,

I have a question concering AngularJS:

In my html-template is a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateData(testVar)">do it</button>
```

If the button is clicked, a function is fired which will update the passed $scope variable.

This variable has following structure:

```
$scope.testVar =
{
id: 1,
name: 'angular',
obj:
{
    obj1: 'object1',
    obj2: 'object2'
}
};
```

This is my function for updating the $scope variable:

```
$scope.updateData = function(param)
{
param = getData();
}

function getData()
{
return {
    id: 2,
    name: 'test',
    obj:
    {
        obj1: 'object3',
        obj2: 'object4'
    }
};
}
```

My Problem is however, after the function is finished, the $scope variable still has the same values as before.

If I update only a property of the variable, it works:

```
param.name = getData().name;
```

I don't understand how extactly that works. I would be pleased if someone could explain this process for me.

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are simply swapping one reference for another. The original reference that the `$scope` points to is the old object.

When you update a single property, then `param` and `$scope.testVar` are still pointing to the same object, and therefore it works as you expect.

Expanding on this a bit, if we write this out in more verbose runtime speak:

**When your controller initializes:**

1. Create a property called `testVar` on the object `$scope`
2. Create an object on the heap `{...}` and assign a reference to it to `$scope.testVar`

**When your function runs:**

3. Get a reference to `testVar` on scope and pass it into the function `updateData()` with the local variable name of `param`
4. Execute `testData()` and create a new object on the heap `{...}`
5. Assign a reference to the new object to the local variable `param`.
6. `param` now points to the new object on the heap, and `$scope.testVar` still points to the same object it did at initialization.

**[Just for posterity]**

7. Execution of `updateData()` finishes, and `param` is popped off the stack.
8. Garbage collector sees that nothing is pointing to the object created by `testData()` and deletes it from the heap by deallocating the memory it took up.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the reference of `param` with a new object instead of assigning to `$scope.testVar`.  Do this instead:

```
$scope.updateData = function() {
   $scope.testVar = getData();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just updating the param value inside functions scope, you would need to update it via $root.testData = getData();